# why PRODUCT_TYPE_downloadable and PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle tags not present in catalog.xml

Tags: magento-1.8, layout

I'm just a beginner in `magento` and I was trying to figure it out that how `magento` handles the product display for different *product types*. Then I come to know about the layout system used by `magento` where all blocks/view are handled by **xml** (correct me if I'm wrong). So, for product view I'd found `catalog.xml` in which four blocks are there for product types

```
PRODUCT_TYPE_simple
PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable
PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped
PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual
```

My question is how these tags are selected/loaded for generating view and what happens to product type `bundle` and `downloadable`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Mage_Catalog :` this is responsible for Simple / Configurable / Virtual / Grouped product types. So those types are defined in Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml

`Mage_Bundle :` this is responsible for Bundle product type. The type has defined in Mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml

`Mage_Downloadable:` this is reponsible for Downloadable products. This type is defined in Mage/Downloadable/etc/config.xml

> How magento renders this product handlers are as below.

`Bundle product type :` app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/bundle.xml

`Downloadable product type :` app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/downloadable.xml

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Bundle)</label>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bundle.js</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle" name="product.info.bundle" as="product_type_data" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle.phtml">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="bundle/catalog_product_price" name="bundle.prices" as="bundle_prices" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/price.phtml">
                <action method="setMAPTemplate"><tmpl>catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml</tmpl></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
        <block type="bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle" name="product.info.bundle.options" as="type_bundle_options" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/options.phtml">
            <action method="addRenderer"><type>select</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select</block></action>
            <action method="addRenderer"><type>multi</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi</block></action>
            <action method="addRenderer"><type>radio</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio</block></action>
            <action method="addRenderer"><type>checkbox</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox</block></action>
        </block>
        <action method="insert"><block>product.info.bundle.options</block></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
        <remove name="product.tierprices" />
        <block type="bundle/catalog_product_view" name="bundle.tierprices" as="tierprices" before="-" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml"/>
        <block type="cataloginventory/qtyincrements" name="product.info.qtyincrements" before="-" template="cataloginventory/qtyincrements.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.clone_prices">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/view/price.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
```

For example I'll put several block names which renders when bundle product is showing.

- The block `bundle/catalog_product_price` is responsible for outputting the `bundle price`
- Outputs `option selection forms` using the `bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle` block
- References `product.clone_prices` to set a block outputting the `final configured price` that uses a bundle-specific template.

For more info refer http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-bundle-product-type-part-1/

Answer (score 3):

For Downloadable product Magento use downloadable.xml
For Bundle Product Magento use bundle.xml

If you want to locate this files then go to your root directory

\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout then find two files which I mention.

Magento Manage using this two xml file for downloadable and bundle product.

Comment: why do these xml are seperated and how do `<PRODUCT_TYPE_type>` rendered?

Comment: Magento provide you five type of products creation so they create the different files for handling different type of stuff.

Comment: this is okay but your answer is not completely satisfying me. can you give me more details about how these xml files are rendered?

Comment: for that you have to read magento Book so you can got proper idea how magento call the xml and phtml files.

Comment: http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide

Comment: http://www.pierrefay.com/

Comment: these are some links you can learn that thing via this links

Comment: http://magestudyguide.com/

Comment: Downloadable and bundled were introduced later in Magento and belong to separate modules, hence the separate layout XML files.

Comment: yes true @benmarks (y)